# Why Local Json file content is not shown in html page?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I want to show the content of json file by using AngularJs (ng-Reapeat) My problem is that the html page cannot show the content of Json file and it is blank!! I have this Json file on my local drive with name, JsonData.json. I have also change the address of the file but it does not work.

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script>

            var test = angular.module("myApp", []);
            test.controller("customersCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
                $http.get("~/Models/JsonData.json").success(function (response) { $scope.names = response.data.records; });
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp"> 
            <div ng-controller="customersCtrl">
                <table>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
                        <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my Json File:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
      "City": "Berlin",
      "Country": "Germany"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Berglunds snabbköp",
      "City": "Luleå",
      "Country": "Sweden"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Wolski Zajazd",
      "City": "Warszawa",
      "Country": "Poland"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Any error on console devtools?

Comment: That's a CORS issue - you don't want your browser to access your local filesystem, do you?

Comment: on line `$http.get("~/Models/JsonData.json").success(function (response) { $scope.names = response.data.records; });` `response` is actually your response data, not the response itself since you're using `success` instead of `then`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822535/ajax-request-from-local-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many (not all) browsers, a page served from a `file://` URL cannot make ajax calls to `file://` URLs; it's a violation of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). `file://` URLs are all defined to have origin "null" which doesn't match anything.

And of course, one served from `http://` can't access a `file://` path because it's cross-origin by definition and `file://` URLs can't offer [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) headers, as there's no web server involved.

Solution: Do your testing from a local web server, not files you open via your file explorer.